# the target table is not updatable (update view)

Tags: mysql

hello i want to update a view using this procedure but i got the error below:
Procedure:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `setijfchauffeur`()
    begin

   declare cnt int;
 declare c int;
 declare cn int;
 declare nomvol varchar(11);
 declare i int;
 declare rest int;
 /*create a table with ID and ARR_num*/
create table ijfnbrvols select distinct ARR_num from ijforder ;
 alter table ijfnbrvols add column ID int primary key auto_increment after       ARR_num;

   select count(*) into cnt from ijfnbrvols ;
   set c = 1;

    while (c<= cnt) do 
     select ARR_num into nomvol from ijfnbrvols where ID = c;
     select count(*) into cn from ijforder where ARR_num = nomvol;
     if (cn <= 3) and (cnt !=0) THEN

   update ijforder set Chauffeur ='berline' where ARR_num = nomvol;

  END IF;

  if (cnt <= 8) and (cnt >=4) THEN

  update ijforder set Chauffeur ='minibus' where ARR_num = nomvol;

   END IF;
  set c= c+1;
   End while;
   END
```

i got this error: Error Code: 1288. The target table ijforder of the UPDATE is not updatable

Help please :) thanks

Comment: Presumably, `ijforder` is a view that cannot be updated.  Edit your question and post its definition.

Comment: Yes **ijforder** is a view but i need to update it

Comment: It appears that you need to update the underlying tables.